# Wayne Manor in Batman v Superman

Tags: dc-extended-universe, film-location, batman-v-superman-dawn-of-justice

Is the burnt out Wayne Manor in Batman v Superman (based) on a real location/stately home  or is it just a CGI model of a 'standard' stately home?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**The burnt Wayne Manor in *Batman v Superman: Dawn of Justice* is based on a real location.**

According to [this article](http://blog.english-heritage.org.uk/digital-doubles-how-to-recreate-a-ruin-for-the-cinema/?_ga=1.58331178.1457853418.1470581430), **Sutton Scarsdale Hall** was used for the burnt Wayne Manor. The company 4DMax, which specializes in data capture for visual effects in movies, used three different kinds of scanners to collect points to map out a 3D model of the building's exterior. During *Batman v Superman*'s post-production, this 3D model was added into the background as Wayne Manor.

[image: Sutton Scarsdale Hall]

Comment: Thanks - I live about 20 minutes from here and I thought it looked a bit like it but wasn't sure.